# Selecting multiple rows in a select queries

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am trying to select multiple columns in a select query in the where clause. When I try to run the query independently, it works but when I connect it with "and" it doesn't work. Right now it currently pulls 0 rows.

```
 Select * from PA_FCS_price_segment
 WHERE MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS012'
  and  MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS013' ;
```

Comment: It might help you read the query if you read the `"and"` as `"and also"`, instead. It's an additional "filter" on your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If think you mean

```
Select * from PA_FCS_price_segment
WHERE (MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS012')
OR    (MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS013');
```

since `MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS012'` and `MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO = 'FCS013'` are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 3):

You can use [in](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm) condition for multiple values:

```
 select * from PA_FCS_price_segment
 WHERE MARKET_FROM ='FCS011' AND MARKET_TO in ('FCS012', 'FCS013')
```

> An in_condition is a membership condition. It tests a value for membership in a list of values or subquery